# Use array values in expressionengine template

Tags: templates, template-scripting

SUMMARY: I need to access an element in an array that is passed to a template from a module and test for it's existence.

I have a function in a module that looks like this:

```
function subscriptions(){
  $subscriptions = array('sub1'=>array(...unimportant data...),
                         'sub4'=>array(...unimportant data...)
                        );
  $data['subscriptions'] = $subscriptions;
  $output = $this->EE->TMPL->parse_variables_row($this->EE->TMPL->tagdata, $data);
  return $output;
}
```

and a template that looks like

{exp:my_module:subscriptions}
  {if subscriptions:sub4}User is subscribed to sub4{/if}
{/exp:my_module:subscriptions}

but that doesn't seem to work. I want to display certain things based upon what subscriptions a user has. This is not just to iterate through and print out subscriptions.

I also tried

```
<?php if($subscriptions['sub4']){ echo 'User is subcribed to sub4' } ?>
```

and it says subscriptions isn't set.

Answer (score 2):

If you want your variables to be in the `subscriptions:sub4` format, you should try this:

```
foreach ($subscriptions as $key => $value) {
  $data['subscriptions:'.$key] = $value;
}
return $this->EE->TMPL->parse_variables_row($this->EE->TMPL->tagdata, $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Rob's got it](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/22252/55) - but just to elaborate, the code you're using in your question would require you to use template code which looks like this:

```
{exp:my_module:subscriptions}
    {subscriptions}
        {if sub4}User is subscribed to sub4{/if}
    {/subscriptions}
{/exp:my_module:subscriptions}
```

The "colon" shortcut which EE uses in Grid and Relationship fields is not a default feature of the `parse_variables()` methods.